# iOS13 system UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, ios13

How to remove the black line at the top of tab,

```
[self.tabBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
self.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];
```

`iOS13` invalid

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the new `UITabBarAppareance` for iOS 13

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appareance = UITabBarAppearance(barAppearance: tabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance)
    appareance.shadowImage = nil
    appareance.shadowColor = nil
    tabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance = appareance
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions.
    tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```